# Is there an easy way to generate RSS/Twitter/Facebook/Digg/Delicious/Reddit links/images for tumblr?

Tags: facebook, twitter, hyperlink, tumblr, digg

I'm looking to generate a bunch of links to add to my tumblr site [Planning for Failure](http://www.planningforfailure.com) for people to share articles on Twitter, Facebook, Digg, Reddit, etc.

I know there are wordpress plugins that do this for you.  I've currently added Facebook and Twitter by hand, but I'm guessing there's an easier way to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://addthis.com/ seems to do the trick.